# New view.frame.y doesn't match up with label.frame.y

Tags: ios, graphics, frame

I have a label on-screen that has its height set as 300px, set to the bottom of the screen, and I want to create a UIView that exactly overlays it.  The code I use is

```
let theFrame = CGRect(x: myLabel.frame.minX, y: myLabel.frame.minY, width: myLabel.frame.width, height: myLabel.frame.height)

newVu = UIView(frame: theFrame)
let newColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
newVu.backgroundColor = newColor
self.view.addSubview(newVu)
```

The result that I get has the new UIView shifted about 20 points higher than the label. ((EDIT: as GeorgeGreen helped me see in Comments, this is because the label is within a Vertical StackView, which is constrained to the bottom of the Top Layout Guide -- thus the Y of the label is relative to the top of the Stack View, not the top of the screen.))  Clearly there are different frames of reference at work, but what is needed to bring everything into the same frame of reference?  EDIT: Or, asked another way, **how can I get the "absolute" X and Y coordinates of the label** ***in the screen***, so that no matter how many views it is embedded in, I can know where to drop a new View to exactly overlay it?

Original screen in IB:

[image: original screen in IB]

Result of the code (new view is semi-transparent; note the yellow band at the bottom):

[image: result of the code -- note yellow band at the bottom]

Comment: Where did you add these code?

Comment: @LuanTran  This code is called from viewWillLayoutSubviews() so that it fires when the view first appears, and then also from viewWillTransition() so that it resets the size when orientation shifts from portrait to landscape and back.  The latter actually updates the newView.frame rather than creating a new view, but the yellow band is there in all cases.

Comment: Can you try moving your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` so that the system has done any auto insetting that it may want to do? Also, I assume that `myLabel` is a direct subview of `self.view`? Out of interest, why not simply `newVu = UIView(frame: myLabel.frame)` for the frame set (though this is not causing you issue)?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen  Did that, putting it into view**Did**LayoutSubviews(), and no change in behavior.  As to why not using `frame: myLabel.frame`, it just didn't occur to me.  The label itself is in a Stack View within the view, and the Stack View.top constraint = Top Layout Guide.bottom.  AH!  That's where the 20px is coming from! Question remains, is there a way to grab "absolute" x and y for the label?  Or better to just add the newView to the Stack View?

Comment: Aha, @LuanTran's answer should sort you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your label position in view by

```
let theFrame = view.convert(myLabel.frame, from: your_stack_view_here)
```

and You should move it to

```
viewDidAppear
```

Because

```
viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

will call any time subview will layout. That's mind at the first time it run, your "mylabel" didn't layout with correct position.

[Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621437-viewwilllayoutsubviews)

Comment: While I agree that `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is earlier than I could/should be calling this, calling it later as in `view**Did**LayoutSubviews` (@George Green's suggestion) or in `viewDidAppear` doesn't change the results I'm getting with the new view being misplaced.

Comment: I did -- the issue is that the label is within a Vertical Stack View, so no matter when I call that code, it produces the same result.  If you had the label not in the Vertical Stack View (whose top is the bottom of the Top LayoutGuide), then things would work right for you, probably even if you called it earlier like I was.  Please see the edit in the question directly above the graphics.

Comment: I see. Did your Verticel Stack View's frame origin y is 20. Base View => Vertical Stack View => Label

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed... the view.convert() answers the question and pulls the coordinates of the label out into the absolute X and Y that I needed.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question of “how can I get the "absolute" X and Y coordinates of the label in the screen”, the answer is to use [UIView.convert(_:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert), passing `nil` as the second parameter. (This will yield coordinates relative to the containing window's origin, but for practical purposes is probably what you mean by “the screen”).